# Is there any omission or abbreviation in this sentence?

Tags: ellipsis

I saw the sentence like 'Attached please find the certificate you requested in PDF format.'
Is there any omission or abbreviation I don't know in the sentence 'Attached please find the certificate you requested in PDF format.'
Please teach me...

Comment: There is no omission. We don't know whether you know the abbreviation PDF or not, but if you don't, you can look it up.

Comment: Adverbial/adjectival ***attached*** would normally occur immediately after the verb ***find*** or after the noun phrase ***the certificate you requested***. The "omission ", such as it is, is that you could have included the "relativizer" ***that*** before ***you requested***, but that's entirely optional.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused by the imperative, which has an implied subject of **you**?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence:

- Attached please find the certificate you requested in PDF format.

is complete as written, and only the relative pronoun "that" can be deemed to be omitted:

- Attached please find the certificate (that) you requested in PDF format.

"Please find ..." is a sentence in the imperative form, and "attached" can be used at the beginning or after the verb "find" to indicate where something (in this case, the certificate requested in PDF format) is to be found: attached to this email, for example.